# cannot successfully forward ssh to docker container in mac os big sur

Tags: macos, docker, ssh, docker-compose, macos-big-sur

I use docker-compose and have a container which pulls from some private git repos so I need to forward host's SSH agent to that container. When developing on a machine with Ubuntu 20.04 I use this configuration and it works just perfectly:

```
services:
  the_service:
    ...
    environment:
      # NOTE set to a path where we mount host's ssh auth socket
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /ssh-agent
    volumes:
      # NOTE mount host's ssh auth socket to be able to access private git repo
      # from within container. this way container uses host's ssh keys.
      - ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:/ssh-agent
      - ./fe:/app
    ...
```

But on a machine with mac OS Big Sur I get an error inside the container when pulling: `permission denied (public key) check if you have correct access rights`. I did some investigation and found that when I execute `ssh-add -l` inside the container I get an error `connection refused`. If I understand it correctly, the forwarding of the SSH socket fails and `ssh-add` cannot connect to SSH agent.

The only solution I've managed to find is to mount `/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock` instead of the path contained in the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable, but the problem is that there's no `/run` directory in my mac OS...

How to solve this issue? Can anyone confirm that forwarding SSH socket to docker on mac OS Big Sur works?

Comment: Turns out mounting `/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock` works, because although the path doesn't exist in host's file system, it acts as some kind of a magic instruction for docker and it then knows what to do.

Comment: This really did work (after hours of Google search, the answer was hidden on this page, in this tiny comment. Thank you!

Comment: also mentioned here for the first time https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/410#issuecomment-552954559